# Jekyll blog folder won't compile on github pages but works offline

Tags: github, sass, jekyll, github-pages

I set up a github user page repo at `myuser.github.io`. I put up a regular html static website in there and it works great. (I also set a custom domain with a CNAME file and CNAME DNS record so that myuser.github.io goes to www.example.com)

Then I also made a `/blog` folder in that repo and I put in a jekyll blog template.

Running `jekyll build serve` or `bundle exec jekyll serve` locally gives me no errors. I can make new posts and they show up on `localhost:4000/blog/`.

But when I push my blog folder to github, these things happen:

- I get an email from github saying "The file `b2/css/main.scss` contains syntax errors. For more information, see
  https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-markdown-errors ."
- If I try to access `www.example.com/blog/index.html` I get a 404.
- If I try, with the /blog/ and the error still in the repo, to make any new changes to my repo (e.g. change the title of my main,
  non-blog page, or change a random image etc) and I push, the changes
  do not register online at all (though they show on github.com in the
  repo file tree).

This means that github freaks out due to that error and won't update until it's fixed.

How can I figure out what that "main.scss" error is? Since it's fine locally.
I am new to jekyll (and github pages) but I followed the documentation as best I could.

This is my main.scss:

```
---
layout: null
# Only the main Sass file needs front matter (the dashes are enough)
#http://sassmeister.com/
---
@charset "utf-8";


// Our variables
$base-font-family: "Raleway",Arial,sans-serif;
$base-font-size:   16px;
$small-font-size:  $base-font-size * 0.875;
$base-line-height: 1.5;

$spacing-unit:     30px;

$text-color:       #111;
$background-color: #fdfdfd;
$brand-color:      #2a7ae2;

$grey-color:       #828282;
$grey-color-light: lighten($grey-color, 40%);
$grey-color-dark:  darken($grey-color, 25%);
$blue-color:       #515865;

// Width of the content area
$content-width:    800px;

$on-palm:          600px;
$on-laptop:        800px;



// Using media queries with like this:
// @include media-query($on-palm) {
//     .wrapper {
//         padding-right: $spacing-unit / 2;
//         padding-left: $spacing-unit / 2;
//     }
// }
@mixin media-query($device) {
    @media screen and (max-width: $device) {
        @content;
    }
}



// Import partials from `sass_dir` (defaults to `_sass`)
@import
        "base",
        "layout",
        "syntax-highlighting"
;
```

PS: this is the jekyll blog theme I am using: https://github.com/smallmuou/Jekyll-Pithy

Comment: Just to make sure: did you follow [this](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/) when setting up?

Comment: In case you'd prefer PHP, there is PHP based app [Scupling](https://github.com/sculpin/sculpin) that does pretty much the same. I've recently set my blog with it after some problems with Jekyll. [There is nice article about it])http://wouterj.nl/2015/02/using-travis-to-build-your-sculpin-blog/).

Comment: Yes, I did follow the github guides. 
PHP sounds nice, I'll check out Scupling as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github pages is generating from the root. If you've put your Jekyll in a `/blog` folder, your `_setting.yml` is not discovered and scss import path can be messed up.

If you want to reproduce locally you have to recreate the same folder architecture and fire the `jekyll serve --trace` from the root, not from /blog.

The solution is to create a `blog` repository and to push your jekyll in the `gh-pages` branch.

Comment: Cheers, David. Makes sense, thought it was automagically detected.

I made a blog repo with a gh-pages branch and now `www.example.com/blog/` shows the jekyll just fine. The thing is that if I go to `example.com/blog` it doesn't direct me to `www.example.com/blog`; it just doesn't get resovled. 

`example.com` automatically gets directed to `www.example.com` and shows the website, but the "subfolder" seems to not be redirected to `www.`. My CNAME is for `www.example.com` any idea why it's not working? Do I need a CNAME inside the blog repo as well?

Comment: Nevermind! I figured out that if I have a CNAME for my main site that's `www.example.com`, and then a CNAME in my blog gh-pages for `blog.example.com`, then if I write `example.com/blog` in my web browser, it does redirect to `www.example.com/blog` and it works.